# Selenium: how to click on the first child of a html element

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriverwait

I'm working on a Selenium Project, and I need to click on the first child of this `ul` got by xpath:

```py
bot.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="mailappcomponent"]/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/ul').click()
```

Can you help me?

Comment: Hi there what seems to be the problem?

Comment: Can you post HTML code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To identify the first child of the `<ul>` element:

```
//*[@id="mailappcomponent"]/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/ul
```

you have to use either the `tag_name` and/or the attributes of the child/descendant element.

In case the first child (descendant) is a **`<li>`** you have to append `/li` at the end as follows:

```
//*[@id="mailappcomponent"]/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/ul/li
```

Incase the first child (descendant) is a **`<ol>`** you have to append `/ol` at the end as follows:

```
//*[@id="mailappcomponent"]/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/ul/ol
```

Now, to click on the element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use either of the following *Locator Strategies*:

```
//in case of descendant li
WebDriverWait(bot, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[@id="mailappcomponent"]/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/ul/li"))).click()
//in case of descendant ol
WebDriverWait(bot, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[@id="mailappcomponent"]/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/ul/ol"))).click()
```

**Note**: You have to add the following imports :

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Answer (score 1):

You Can Click on First list item by using XPATH

```py
bot.find_element_by_xpath('//[@id="mailappcomponent"]/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/ul/li[1]').click()
```

If want to click on second third and so on just change `/li[number you want]`